# Redux: How can I have two reducers respond to the same action in a certain order?

Tags: redux

I'm relatively new to Redux, and I have the following situation:

1. My app makes an AJAX request to fetch the first "message" object from the server
2. The response comes back and dispatches `{type: 'RECEIVE_FIRST_MESSAGE', message}`
3. My `MessageReducer` handles `RECEIVE_FIRST_MESSAGE` by:

   A) adding `action.message` to `state.messages`

   B) making another AJAX call to fetch the next message (if `action.message.hasNextMessage`)
4. My `SessionReducer` also handles `RECEIVE_FIRST_MESSAGE`, by adding `action.message.sessionId` to `state.session.id`

There's only one problem: when I fetch the second message, I need to use the `sessionId` I got from the first message.  But because `MessageReducer` runs before `SessionReducer`, the session ID isn't in the state at the time the `MessageReducer` tries to make the second AJAX request.

I could "solve" this by making using a timeout to ensure `MessageReducer` doesn't make it's second request until 1ms later, but that feels like a hack/anti-pattern.

**TLDR**

When I have:

- an action which has data for two parts of the `state` (handled by two different reducers)
- I want to trigger an AJAX call in response, from reducer A
- I want to add some state (`state.session.id`) in response, from reducer B

how can I ensure that reducer B adds the state before reducer A makes the AJAX call (in a way that wouldn't make Dan Abramov cry)?

Comment: Are you using anything like redux thunks or sagas? Why would it need to get it from the session if it's already in the message you're processing? But: you're making an Ajax call in a reducer?

Comment: Yes I am using thunks.  As for why I'd get the ID from the `state` ... I guess now that I think about it, I don't.  I was just thinking "one action adds the ID to the state, a separate action pulls the ID from the state", but since (as you noted) I already have everything I need in the action, passing the ID through the `state` is completely unnecessary (well, except for later requests, but those don't have timing problems).  Thanks!  If you want to put something to the effect of "by definition in this case you already have everything you need" I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first. Never make an AJAX call from inside a reducer. Ever. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-lv8kyYrqQ

Reducer functions are supposed to be pure, without any side effects (like HTTP requests). Instead, use thunks to your advantage. Below is an example of how you might do this.

After getting the first message response back from the server, you dispatch the `RECEIVE_FIRST_MESSAGE` action. This will update the state atom synchronously. Once that's complete, you can check to see if the message has a next message. If it does, dispatch a new async action to get the next message. Inside that async action creator, you can get the session ID from the state atom, which is guaranteed to be updated in response to the `RECEIVE_FIRST_MESSAGE` action you dispatched earlier.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
// getFirstMessageFromServer() and getNextMessageFromServer() are thunks and async action creators
// fetchFirstMessage() and fetchNextMessage() make HTTP requests

function getFirstMessageFromServer() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return fetchFirstMessage()
      .then(message => {
        dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_FIRST_MESSAGE', message });
        if (message.hasNextMessage) dispatch(getNextMessageFromServer());
        return message;
      });
  };
}

function getNextMessageFromServer() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { id: sessionId } = getState().session.id;
    return fetchNextMessage(sessionId)
      .then(nextMessage => {
        dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_NEXT_MESSAGE', message: nextMessage });
        return nextMessage;
      });
  };
}


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  session: sessionReducer,
  messages: messagesReducer
});

const initialMessages = [];

function messagesReducer(state = initialMessages, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'RECEIVE_FIRST_MESSAGE':
      return state.concat(action.message);
    case 'RECEIVE_NEXT_MESSAGE':
      return state.concat(action.message);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const initialSession = { id: null };

function sessionReducer(state = initialSession, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'RECEIVE_FIRST_MESSAGE':
      return {
        ...state,
        id: action.message.sessionId
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense: when I have a minute I'll try to refactor the delegate calls out of the reducer, and follow your pattern.  Thanks.